# How to type a function with arbitrary arguments in TypeScript, without using any?

Tags: typescript

As shown in [TypeScript type signatures for functions with variable argument counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739149/typescript-type-signatures-for-functions-with-variable-argument-counts), a function with an arbitrary number of arguments (potentially of differing types) can be typed as follows:

```
interface Example {
    func(...args: any[]): void;
}
```

If we assume using `any` is not allowed, how could we type the callback function `bar` below?

`foo` should be able to accept any callback with an arbitrary number of arguments with different types (we do not know the types at compile time).

`foo` should also be able to call `bar`, with an arbitrary number of arguments. As such, [Alternative for "any function" ((...args: any[]) => any) without using any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75629945/alternative-for-any-function-args-any-any-without-using-any) does not address this question.

```
const foo = (bar: (...rest: unknown[]) => void) => {
  bar('asdf');
}

const bar = (one: string) => {
  console.log(one);
  return 'bar';
}

foo(bar);
```

The above generates the following error message on `foo(bar)`:

```
Argument of type '(one: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...rest: unknown[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'one' and 'rest' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2345)
```

I also tried using a generic type parameter to delegate the type setting to the caller of `foo`, as follows:

```
const foo = <T>(bar: (...rest: T[]) => void) => {
   bar('asdf');
}
```

The above generates the following error message on `bar('asdf')`:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'. ts(2345)
```

Finally, I tried using `never` as suggested in the comments, but that renders `bar` un-callable:

```
const foo = (bar: (...rest: never[]) => void) => {
  bar('asdf');
}
```

Error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: You may wish to see https://stackoverflow.com/q/75629945/20536082.

Comment: I made an edit to clarify why the linked post does not address the question.

Comment: So you want a type that accepts any function whatsoever (e.g., `const f = (x: string) => x.toUpperCase()`) but which also lets you *call* the function with any arguments you want (e.g., `f(123)`)? That’s not type-safe at all (the example above explodes at runtime) and `any` is the way to allow that. What do you care about more here, “don’t allow `any`” or “be type-safe”? If both, then you’re asking for something inconsistent. What do you want to do here?

Comment: (see prev comment) of course the above is all mentioned in the linked q/a, so I'm not sure how it doesn't fully address your question (which is not the same as meeting your needs).  You *could* use the `Function` type, which is intentionally unsafe but doesn't happen to use `any`. That might work, but it seems like a weird use case where you want to avoid `any` but allow `Function`, which is like complying with a "no smoking" rule by lighting a cigarette but not actually putting it in your mouth. Could you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a million. As you pointed out I think I was actually asking for something that was indeed not type safe (or good JS practice). I read in the handbook that a function signature should be written from the callers perspective, not based on the passed in callback. That fits your point on it not making sense to call the function if we do not know compile-time what the args are. So, if I do not know the args, then I should not call it. Additionally, it is OK for the callback to have less args than the parameter signature, as extra args will just be ignored.

Comment: @jcalz Currently working on your write-up of variance, in the context of understanding which callbacks can be passed to which signatures (related to what i did not understand in the OP above). Helpful (though a bit of a brain twister).

Comment: @jcalz Related to the above, if you have time: Imagine a function `foo` that accepts a callback with type: `(param: string | number) => void`. Then I pass in this function: `(one: string) => {}`. Here, TS errors because `string | number` could not be assigned to `string`. I expected it to be the other way around, i.e. that TS attempts to assign the actual passed in callback (which has a parameter with a narrower type) to the signature which has a wider parameter type (`(param: string | number) => void`). So, I expected it to work by narrowing parameter from `string | number` to `string`

Comment: @jcalz The error message is: `Argument of type '(one: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(param: string | number) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'one' and 'param' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`. Thus, it does do the assignment of the callback in the order I expected, but then reverses the assignment direction when evaluating the callback's parameter.

Comment: @jcalz I created a new question here, to avoid going off topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142644/when-assigning-callbacks-in-typescript-parameters-are-assigned-in-the-opposite