# When assigning callbacks in TypeScript, parameters are assigned in the opposite direction of the callback itself. Why is that?

Tags: typescript

When calling a function with an argument, the argument type is assigned to the parameter type. In other words, the argument type must be equal to, or narrower than, the parameter type.

Example:

```
const foo = (bar: string | number) => {
  console.log(bar);
}

foo('bar');
```

The above works fine because `'bar'` (a string literal type) is assignable to `string | number`.

Now, consider a callback scenario instead:

```
const foo = (bar: (baz: string | number) => void) => {
  bar('baz');
  // We should probably also have a call with a numeric parameter here, like bar(42),
  // since the callback signature implies that it is also called that way.
}

const bar = (baz: string) => {}

foo(bar);
```

We get this error message on `bar('baz')`:

```
Argument of type '(baz: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(baz: string | number) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'baz' and 'baz' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

As seen, in the callback case, TS attempts to assign type `(baz: string) => void` (the argument type) to `(baz: string | number) => void` (the parameter type). That was as expected.

The parameter of the callback, however, is assigned in the opposite direction: Type `string | number` (parameter of callback argument) is assigned to type `string` (parameter of callback parameter).

How come the assignment direction of the parameters in the callback are inverted from the non-callback scenario?

Comment: Contravariance! See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoonjW).  Your `foo` call signature means that inside `foo`, someone is free to call the callback with a numeric input, right? (otherwise you'd have made it `(baz: string) => void` instead of `(baz: string | number) => void`). So that means you should not pass in any function which assumes a `string` input.  Functions are contravariant in their inputs for that reason. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think you are spot on. I probably do not understand the contravariance concept well enough, and why/how it applies here. I did read your post on it, and a couple of other related articles, but most of them speak about contravariance as applying to generics (type parameters) extending one another (contravariance being if `T` extends `U`, then `F<U>` extends `F<T>`). I guess it also applies outside of `extends` scenarios, but I am not sure how. I am also hoping this will make more sense later: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant

Comment: Anything that works for generics should (in theory) work when you plug in types for a generic.  So if `F<T>` is `(arg: T) => void`, then `F` is contravariant in `T`, meaning that `F<string | number> extends F<string>` but not vice versa, which looks like "`(arg: string | number) => void` extends `(arg: string) => void` but not vice versa", exactly what's going on here.  I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz We are probably also coming back to the point that callback signatures should always be written from the caller's perspective. As you show in your playground example, there should be another call in the function with a numeric argument. Once we add that, it becomes more clear why passing in a callback which only accepts a string parameter would be wrong....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "always be written from the caller's perspective", but functions are indeed written as *call signatures* so you have to think about how they are called, yes.

Comment: @jcalz Re. "callers perspective", it was just something I picked up here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters (Function signatures are always read from the caller's perspective.)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the context and in advance for an answer. It seems `T extends U` is used interchangeably with `T is assignable to U`. Is that right? I guess it follows from this logic: If T extends U, then T is a subset of U, meaning T can be assigned to U (we can always assign a subset type to a superset type to narrow down the superset).

Comment: More or less, yes.  There are some details where "extends", "assignable", and "is a subtype of" are not completely synonymous, but they are fiddly and usually not worth talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see that assignments go "in the opposite direction", you could say they "counter-vary".  Indeed, [function types are *contravariant* in their input types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types).  So a function of the form `(x: X) => void` is assignable to `(y: Y) => void` if `Y` is assignable to `X`, not vice versa.  In particular, `(baz: string | number) => void` is assignable to `(baz: string) => void`, but `(baz: string) => void` is *not* assignable to `(baz: string | number) => void`.

This can be seen by adding more functionality to your code that conforms to the types.  First, inside `foo()`, the `bar` parameter is supposed to accept `string | number`, so you can call `bar()` with any string or numeric argument you want.  Let's make sure we do both:

```
const foo = (bar: (baz: string | number) => void) => {
    bar('baz');
    bar(123); // <-- this is okay too
}
```

Then `bar` accepts only a `baz` argument of type `string`, meaning that it should be fine to treat `baz` as a string, like calling its `toUpperCase()` method:

```
const bar = (baz: string) => { baz.toUpperCase() } // <-- this is okay too
```

Now,

```
foo(bar); // error
//  ~~~ <-- Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

gives you that same compiler error (and nothing has changed from the type system's point of view). Due to contravariance, the error message is telling you that `(baz: string) => void` is not assignable to `(baz: string | number) => void` because `string | number` is not assignable to `string`.

And if you actually run this code without fixing the error, you'll get a runtime error that `baz.toUpperCase` [is not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function).

The fact that a function can handle a `string` does not imply that it can handle a `string | number`.

---

On the other hand, it's perfectly fine to *widen* the function input:

```
const qux = (baz: string | number | boolean) => {
    if (typeof baz === "string") {
        console.log(baz.toUpperCase())
    } else if (typeof baz === "number") {
        console.log(baz.toFixed())
    } else {
        console.log(baz === true)
    }
}

foo(qux); // okay
```

That works because any function which can handle a `string | number | boolean` can definitely handle a `string | number`.  There's no runtime error because inside `qux()` one does not just write `baz.toUpperCase()` without checking to see if it's a `string`.  (And if you tried to do that, you'd get a compiler error *there* saying that `number` and `boolean` don't have `toUpperCase()` methods).

---

So that's why things are assigned in the opposite direction for function inputs. They counter-vary because of the direction data moves.  A piece of data needs to be no wider than the box it goes into.  So you can always safely make that box bigger or the data smaller, but not vice versa.  For function parameters, data is coming *in*, meaning that the function can make the input parameter wider but not narrower.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUAjAhgJwFzrYBeB0OAlmAOYwA+MYArgLYYCmOAlCgHwwBuIcgBNuyPgG8AUDFkxsONAHJiSzgG4ZchWgCMAJgDMGmAHpTMADwBaazCgALchBjOYIANZYAngBoYFFQOUAD8cjBSAL5SUqCQsAoohFgkMGSUVGKS8ikAdFAgAKoADsUcAMJYEGxo3JFmFjZ2jm5unj7+gcEhMQggmLgm5jAcOCA48OMwVIjCAWxV4FKmAFQwANoAogBK2wC6BABEmwAebMCMUGxzAFJY-FgAysAUxbAAYljkADbXeIcRLa7A45Ij5IqlCpVNiuFxgECwLDwRhgYBQcjgGArUwxOLQGAAR0YJySA1S6WodAYLHYE3oGEQvywYCyMGk4XIcHQUG8ZRAXOIKGQqEOFKoh247PCcjxIF+uW+ICoZPBJTKOEq1VqnC0snqbG+1VcXLQPL5ApSQpFTFYHAlbN10tl8sVyuI4Pe5DOwm1jv1hphUulMGdbAVSrJVvsOEYbB14Wi0T6aCJJyGFna3iAA)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Side note, but how do you think about the word extends in the context of constraining a type? To me, extends sounds like you are making something bigger/wider, when in fact, in TS, T extends Y means T is equal to or smaller than Y. A silly side point, I just found the word a bit confusing and thought I might be thinking of it wrong. However, when it comes to object types, extends has the meaning I would naturally apply to it (i.e. by extending an object type we are adding properties to it, thus making it bigger).

Comment: Object types are contravariant in their keys, so that's the likely source of the confusion.  `extends` originally comes from class/interface extension where you add properties, which makes the *key type* wider and therefore the *object type* narrower (`{a: string, b: string}` is more specific than `{a: string}`).  But TS uses `extends` for all subtype relations, including things like `"a" extends "a" | "b"`.

Comment: In case it is helpful to future visitors: Since we are adding a callback signature two places, I found it helpful to think of the function that calls the callback as the one holding the *call signature*. And the *call signature* should define how the function can be *called*. So, if we pass in a callback that does not match how the function can be called, TS should (and does) throw an error.

Comment: One small addon question re. the objects, does what you said in the comment mean that: Object B is assignable to object A, if and only if union type of property types in object B is assignable to union type of property types in object A? I didn't quite get that part.

Comment: Finally, it might also be helpful to add that the function `foo` can be more easily used with different callbacks if we make it generic and pass in the callback's parameter as the second argument: `const foo = <T>(bar: (baz: T) => void, param: T) => { bar(param) }`. Then it can be called with any callback that has one parameter: `foo(bar, 'foo')`. Here, TS will infer type of T from that second parameter, and use it as the type of the callback's parameter (in the callback's *call signature*). Now we do not have to manually ensure the parameter types are assignable in the right direction.

Comment: Not "if and only if", but if `T extends U` then `keyof U extends keyof T`. (the opposite isn't always true because you lose information with `keyof`).  If `T` is `{a: string, b: number}` and `U` is `{a: string}`, then `{a: string, b: number} extends {a: string}` implies that `"a" extends "a" | "b"`.